# WebGL rendering to a specific mip map level

Tags: webgl

Is it possible to render to a specific mipmap level of a render target in webgl?

Why is level in framebufferTexture2D always set to zero?

> The mipmap level of the texture image to attach. Always set to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [according to the spec section 4.4.3](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf)

> level specifies the mipmap level of the texture image to be attached to the framebuffer and must be 0. Otherwise, INVALID_VALUE is generated.

That's a limitation of OpenGL ES 2.0 which WebGL is based on

Comment: i was not even familiar with the full spec, i mostly tried to make sense out of this, https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/

Comment: Section 1.1 of the WebGL spec says WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 and links to the spec linked above.

Comment: hi gman, section 4.4 in the es 3.0 spec doesnt mention anything specifically for the level argument, if im reading this correctly. Therefore this should be possible with webgl 2?

Comment: Yes, [it should work in WebGL 2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance2/renderbuffers/framebuffer-test.html?webglVersion=2&quiet=0)